# How to use 'sync_original_prompt' from pxssh module

Tags: python, unit-testing, pexpect, pxssh

```
>>> from pexpect import pxssh
>>> s=pxssh.pxssh()
>>> s.login('IP','USER','PASSWORD',auto_prompt_reset=True)
True
>>> s.sendline('echo Test');
10
>>> s.prompt()
True
>>> s.after
'[PEXPECT]# '
>>> s.PROMPT='BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:'
>>> s.sendline('bteq .logon dbc,dbc')
20
>>> s.prompt()
True
>>> s.after
'BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:'
>>> s.sendline('quit;')
6
>>> s.prompt()
False
>>> s.PROMPT='[PEXPECT]# '
>>> s.prompt()
False
>>> s.sync_original_prompt()
True
>>> s.prompt()
False
```

As per my understanding after `s.sync_original_prompt()`,  `PROMPT` variable should reset to initial prompt, which is `[PEXPECT]#` here, and `s.prompt()` should result in `True`. But it doesn't. Can anybody please tell me how to reset `PROMPT` variable to original prompt? and how to use `sync_original_prompt` attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The initial `s.PROMPT` (a regexp string) is actually `'\\[PEXPECT\\][\\$\\#] '`, not `[PEXPECT]#`. I'd suggest you write like this:

  ```
  savePrompt = s.PROMPT

  s.PROMPT = 'a-new-prompt'
  s.sendline('bteq ...')
  s.prompt()                 # expect the new prompt

  s.PROMPT = savePrompt      # restore the saved prompt
  s.sendline('quit;')
  s.prompt()                 # expect the saved prompt
  ```
- `sync_original_prompt()` should be used like this:

  ```
  s.sync_original_prompt() # this make sure you are at the prompt
  s.set_unique_prompt()    # change the shell's prompt to the default PROMPT
  s.sendline('run some command')
  s.prompt()
  ```